# Cant start piranha MVC from empty template

Tags: piranha-cms

I'm trying to make use of piranha CMS. 
The manager works fine, but here's what I get when trying to view a page

[image]

What can be wrong ? where can I look for issues ? 
(I updated all the packages, pulled in latest piranha from nuget "Install-Package PiranhaCMSMvc"

Use VS2013, and a empty project template
My web config http://1drv.ms/1gkxD44

Here's my Route's.
It did Add an extra file with piranha routes instead of overwriting it. 
But the code was identical. So I moved it from there to the default Route file

[image]

Comment: I've faced with the same problem. How have you solved it?

Comment: Look at the comments below. The @KingOfHypocrites attached a sample solution that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post your routing config... I would think your issue is routing. Comparing my web.config and yours, I notice a few differences... You are targeting 4.5.1 and mine is set to framework 4.5. **I also had to set a binding redirect for razor**, although maybe this wasn't an issue for you.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor"
        publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I think it's worthy of comparison because I have a fresh installation with nothing added by me using the nuget package.

All of that being said, I would look to the routing as it appears it is not redirecting to the home controller. When you run the installation it should have asked you if it could rewrite your routing file. Did you allow it to do so?

**Edit:**
See my updated comments and example project.

Comment: Tried out Your comments, didn't help :(

Comment: This time I created a new project in VS 2013 (MVC 4 Empty), instead of VS 2012 (MVC 4 Basic). I installed the package from the console and setup ran as expected. Once I wired up my database, my post came up fine. I did have to make this one change which I mentioned previously:       <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor"
            publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>

Comment: Also I'm assuming you updated your connection string as explained in the instructions, otherwise I don't think you would have been able to do anything with the manager. Here is my project. Be sure to update connection string: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9AE1BB382E032!211&authkey=!AGCFdDEXuTjFoVU&ithint=file%2c.zip

Comment: I see. Your project worked fine for me too. But.. Piranha doc's clearly state - that MVC 5.1 is a requirement.. That must have been the issue

Comment: Is or isn't a requirement? If you look the project I made has the 5.1 package installed. Glad it's working for you now!

Comment: So what was the problem?