# Piranha MVC HTTP 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: piranha-cms

I've created ASP.NET MVC Empty project and installed Piranha MVC using NuGet `Install-Package PiranhaCMSMvc`. The manager works but I can't open any page. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417692/cant-start-piranha-mvc-from-empty-template) didn't help me

here is my web config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="piranha" type="Piranha.ConfigFile, Piranha" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="PiranhaCMS" timeout="30" />
    </authentication>
    <sessionState timeout="30" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <piranha>
    <settings>
      <managerNamespaces value="" />
      <disableManager value="false" />
      <passiveMode value="false" />
      <prefixlessPermalinks value="false" />
    </settings>
    <providers>
      <mediaProvider value="Piranha.IO.LocalMediaProvider, Piranha" />
      <mediaCacheProvider value="Piranha.IO.LocalMediaCacheProvider, Piranha" />
      <cacheProvider value="Piranha.Cache.WebCacheProvider, Piranha" />
      <logProvider value="Piranha.Log.LocalLogProvider, Piranha" />
    </providers>
  </piranha>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="Piranha.Web.APIKeyAuthorization, Piranha" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="piranha" connectionString="data source=myDbServer;initial catalog=EHRHome;user id=sa;password=*****;multipleactiveresultsets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you try to access a page directly, i.e /home/your-permalink to check if there's something wrong with the default start page route?

Comment: Default rout for `http://localhost:43142/` says `HTTP 404.0 - Not Found http://localhost:43142/page?permalink=start&piranha-culture=en-EN` and route for `http://localhost:43142/home/start` says the same `HTTP 404.0 - Not Found http://localhost:43142/page/?permalink=start&piranha-culture=en-EN`

Answer (score 1):

If the route /page is not found then the controllers included in the template project must be missing. Make sure that you have the PageController & PostController present in your Controllers folder.

Also, the controllers and RouteConfig included are C#, so if you're using VB you'll have to Convert them in order for them to function.

When you create the project in VS, make sure you check the option to include MVC into your project, otherwise your project won't have a Global.asax and the routes won't be configured!

Hope this helps!